# CSS Line Heights being off

Tags: css

I have an `<a>` with some text in. I have set a font-size and a line-height on the a but the text sticks out the bottom of the a.

How can this be resolved?

[image]

Markup:

```
<a href="#" class="prev-link>Previous photo</a>
```

Styles:

```
.prev-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: red;
  background-color: #102c3b;
}
```

Any ideas?

This pic shows what happens when I set line-height to normal. It fits the text but leaves a top gap?

[image]

Comment: Just remove the line height.. that's the problem. Alternatively, just increase it.

Comment: If I remove the line-height, it defaults back to my globally set line-height.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the ideal relationship between line-height, font-size, and paragraph margin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025266/whats-the-ideal-relationship-between-line-height-font-size-and-paragraph-marg)

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked. If the intent is to make some text appear in a box that is just as large as needed to accommodate all the glyphs, then this should be said explicitly, and then the question might in effect be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587369/increasing-the-text-size-of-unicode-symbol-occupies-too-much-margin

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
line-height: 1em;
```

into

```
line-height: 1.5em;
```

If you set line-height to 1 em and have font-size 18px, it means that 1 em = 18px so line-height will be the same as font-size.

Comment: I could do that but surely setting the line height to the same as the font size should fit the text inside that height perfectly.?  Also, If I set `line-height: normal`, the text fits in at the top but has a lot of top space. No padding is set.

Comment: I realise 1em is 18px in my case. No issues there. But in practice the text drops out of the bottom.

Comment: You should probably look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857654/line-height-does-not-match-the-font-size

Comment: If you know exact text that will be displayed you probably can set line-height to 1, and add padding-bottom to a element. But in my opinion it such changes shouldn't be done because when user zooms in in his browser everything could look illegible

Answer (score 0):

for example , you can add

```
<a href="#" class="prev-link><span>Previous photo</span></a>

.prev-link span {
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }
.prev-link { 
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
border-width: 0;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1em;
color: red;
background-color: #102c3b;
}
```

Comment: That's a total hack though? Surely the text should fit perfectly in the line-height set?

Answer (score 0):

```
line-height:normal;
```

Should reset the line-height of the text to default, ignoring your global reset css you may have. Though using it, may lead to the actual line-height depend on user agent.

You should probably try to stick to either px or em when defining typography. Ie. you got:

```
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1em;
```

Which may cause issues you described.

One interesting thing about fonts is, that the baseline is not where you'd visually expect it to be.

Your situation looks like the line-height is calculated around ascender and baseline.

See here: http://www.myfirstfont.com/glossary.html